# Webpack stopped watching one particular file as well as new files

Tags: npm, npm-watch

I've been using webpack for 2 years without issue.  However, as of yesterday, I noticed that new files weren't being re-compiling when calling npm run dev.  In addition, one of my files which has always recompiled (one that already existed) has stopped re-compiling.

After playing around with this for a while I'm actually seeing that some more interesting behavior

```
resources
 /js 
   /components
   /pages
   /store
   /router
   /plugins
```

All of my current files outside of the components file recompile.  Every file in components recompile except for a single file (MyQuestions.vue). In addition if I add new files to that folder, they won't recompile.  Further if I create a new folder, no files in the new folder will recompile (I thought maybe components was corrupted and I could just create a new folder).

In my scripts field in my package.json I see:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue resources/js"
  },
```

In addition, my webpack.mix.js is:

```
    const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
require('laravel-mix-versionhash')
// const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')

mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/dist/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/dist/css')
  .disableNotifications()

const ASSET_URL = process.env.ASSET_URL ? process.env.ASSET_URL + '/' : '/'
console.log('Asset URL: ' + ASSET_URL)

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  // console.log(process.env);
  mix
    // .extract() // Disabled until resolved: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1889
    // .version() // Use `laravel-mix-versionhash` for the generating correct Laravel Mix manifest file.
    .versionHash()
} else {
  mix.sourceMaps()
}
const webpack = require('webpack')

mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/), // Locales were causing a css error in app.css
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.ASSET_PATH': JSON.stringify(ASSET_URL)
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/js')
    }
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'dist/js/[chunkhash].js',
    path: mix.config.hmr ? '/' : path.resolve(__dirname, './public/build'),
    publicPath: ASSET_URL
  }
})

mix.then(() => {
  if (!mix.config.hmr) {
    process.nextTick(() => publishAseets())
  }
})

function publishAseets () {
  const publicDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './public')

  if (mix.inProduction()) {
    fs.removeSync(path.join(publicDir, 'dist'))
  }

  fs.copySync(path.join(publicDir, 'build', 'dist'), path.join(publicDir, 'dist'))
  fs.removeSync(path.join(publicDir, 'build'))
}

/* mix
  .js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css");*/
```

Comment: That’s not something npm has built in. We need details on your environment

Comment: `npm run <cmd>` does not correlate to anything directly in the npm CLI, but rather your `scripts` field in your package.json.  Furthermore, this means the “watch” and “prod” commands you’ve labeled have no context in this post, so you’ll wanna includes what those scripts actually do. Lastly, you likely need to mention what file watcher you’re using, such as nodemon, node-dev (ts-node-dev), etc.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  The initial file that I was testing was a Vue component that I was no longer using anywhere (not imported into a different script).  It seems that webpack will only recompile when a file is actually being used.  Never noticed this before.  I then repeated the process by creating new directories/files and sure enough, once I imported them into another script, they were compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. The initial file that I was testing was a Vue component that I was no longer using anywhere (not imported into a different script). It seems that webpack will only recompile when a file is actually being used. Never noticed this before. I then repeated the process by creating new directories/files and sure enough, once I imported them into another script, they were compiled.